# Material Components Confirmation Dialog

Tags: android, material-design, android-alertdialog, material-components-android

How can I implement the horizontal dividers or the elevation which can be seen on the Title and Buttons in the dialog box in the following image?

[image: Confirmation Dialog]

I have installed the material components library and used the [dialog documentation](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md) as a guide.

The code is as follows:

```java
MaterialAlertDialogBuilder materialAlertDialogBuilder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this.getActivity());

LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_settings, null);

setupView(view);


materialAlertDialogBuilder.setView(view);
materialAlertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Settings");

materialAlertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {

    }
});

materialAlertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
    {

    }
});

materialAlertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
materialAlertDialogBuilder.create();
materialAlertDialogBuilder.show();
```

The `MaterialAlertDialogBuilder` does not seem to have the ability to set this property.

Comment: @JeelVankhede the style does not exist

Comment: @JeelVankhede, unfortunately, none of the styles results in the above image

Comment: okay.. my bad.. just trying to help 

Comment: Please take note that the image above is supposed to be a mockup and is not meant to represent the actual native implementation in Android.

Comment: @Edric its a shame looked pretty cool. Thought maybe there was a style I could use instead of having to do the "heavy lifting" myself

Comment: @George You can obtain it.

Comment: @Edric It is not a mockup.It exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the standard [`MaterialAlertDialogBuilder`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Dialog.md).
It is the default behavior if you have the title panel, the button panel and a content that requires a scrollable view.

For example:

```
    CharSequence[] choices = {"Choice1", "Choice2", "Choice3", "Choice1", "Choice2", "Choice3","Choice1", "Choice2", "Choice3","Choice1", "Choice2", "Choice3","Choice1", "Choice2", "Choice3","Choice1", "Choice2", "Choice3"};
    boolean[] choicesInitial = {false, true, false, false, true, false,false, true, false,false, true, false, false, true, false,false, true, false};

    new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(MainActivity.this)
        .setTitle("Title")
        .setMultiChoiceItems(choices, choicesInitial, null)
        .setPositiveButton("ok", null)
        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
        .show();
```

[image]

Using a long message, with the title and buttons you can obtain:

```
new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(AlertDialogActivity.this)
            .setTitle("Title")
            .setMessage(multiLineMessage.toString())
            .setPositiveButton("ok", null)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .show();
```

[image]

Comment: Is possible to always display horizontal divider even the content is not scrollable with MaterialAlertDialog?